# using draw_networkx(), How to show multiple drawing windows?

Tags: networkx

The following code will create only one window at a time, the second window will only show when the first one is closed by the user.

How to show them at the same time with different titles?

```
nx.draw_networkx(..a..)
nx.draw_networkx(..b..)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It works the same as making other plots with Matplotlib.
Use the figure() command to switch to a new figure.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
G=nx.cycle_graph(4)
H=nx.path_graph(4)

plt.figure(1)
nx.draw(G)
plt.figure(2)
nx.draw(H)
    
plt.show()
```

Comment: by the way, how to set the canvas-size of figure before they are shown?

Comment: The figure() function takes a size as an argument: figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

Comment: What if you want to plot two networks in two subplots next to one another?

Answer (score 3):

You can use matplotlib and a grid to show multiple graphs:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Draw a graph with matplotlib.
You must have matplotlib for this to work.
"""
__author__ = """Aric Hagberg (hagberg@lanl.gov)"""
#    Copyright (C) 2004-2008
#    Aric Hagberg <hagberg@lanl.gov>
#    Dan Schult <dschult@colgate.edu>
#    Pieter Swart <swart@lanl.gov>
#    All rights reserved.
#    BSD license.

try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
except:
    raise

import networkx as nx

G=nx.grid_2d_graph(4,4)  #4x4 grid

pos=nx.spring_layout(G,iterations=100)

plt.subplot(221)
nx.draw(G,pos,font_size=8)

plt.subplot(222)
nx.draw(G,pos,node_color='k',node_size=0,with_labels=False)

plt.subplot(223)
nx.draw(G,pos,node_color='g',node_size=250,with_labels=False,width=6)

plt.subplot(224)
H=G.to_directed()
nx.draw(H,pos,node_color='b',node_size=20,with_labels=False)

plt.savefig("four_grids.png")
plt.show()
```

Code above will generates this figure:

[image]

Reference: https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9/examples/drawing/four_grids.html